# how to convert NSString to NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsmutablearray, plist

i have an NSString that is value in plist format. i download this string from url. but i dont wanna write it to a file. when the string comes Asynchronous, i want to put it to nsmutablearray.
how can i convert string (in plist format) to nsmutablearray?
there is some methods, initWithContentsOfURL, initWithContentsOfFile. but no intiwithstring.

this method works Synchronous:
NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a `-propertyList` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/propertyList) in NSString.

```
NSMutableArray* tmpArray = [[theString propertyList] mutableCopy];
...
[tmpArray release];
```

Note that this method will throw an exception (i.e. throw) if the string is not in plist format. To have a better error checking, try to download the data as NSData, and use the [NSPropertyListSerialization methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:).

Comment: thanx, i used NSPropertyListSerialization.